# JPA + SQL : Query with percentage in setMaxResults

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa-2.0

In SQL I can write a query as below.

```
Select top 10 percent from table
```

The above query will give me top 10 percentage rows. How can I achieve the same in JPA query.?

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("Select t from table t");
q.setMaxResults(10);
```

The above gives top 10 records. I want something like top 10 percentage which is 100 for a table with 1000 records.

PS: Apologies for alignment n code. Typed in mobile due to office firewall.

Comment: In SQL one CANNOT write `Select top 10 percent from table` ) That is Microsoft's proprietary extension. That's why JPAQL / Hibernate do not support it. Btw what would be the expectation for 'top 10 percent' from the `Select top 10 percent from table` ? Top 10 percent according to what?

Comment: I missed the order by clause. It was supposed to something similar to top 10 percent usage etc etc...

Comment: Thank you anyway. Didn't know that it was not implemented.